# When to use ViewModel or Partial View

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Should I use view model or partial view? Or when is it advantageous to use one over the other? In my particular case I am going to be submitting data to the server or using an http post.

Comment: Those are two very different things.  You appear to be confusing your terminology.  Can you provide an example of something you've actually tried which isn't working in some way?

Comment: I want a view that shows Store purchases. But I also want a section of my view to show items purchased as well as allow the user to (Add) items purchased. Keep in mind that I have two separate entities... Stores and Items Purchased.  I was using a partial view for this but i was wondering should i use a view model to do this.

Comment: Partial views and view models are not mutually exclusive alternatives of the same functionality.  They’re very different things.  It sounds like you have working code and are wondering if there’s some way to improve that code.  That would be a question for the Code Review SE site.  Be sure to include the code in question to demonstrate what you’re currently doing.

Answer (score 0):

These are different things. View Model is something similar to a parameter to some function. And Partial View is something like a body of a function called from other function. So you can pass some view model to a partial view while creating a request result at a response to submitting data to your server on http post.

You might find helpful this tutorial to better understand this - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/adding-a-view

Comment: I understand that a view model is simply an object that is sent to a view for displaying data. It offers you more flexibility in shaping your data and the UI that is displayed to the user  than passing a domain model. Also I understand that a partial view is rendered inside of a view. So using this scenario I guess my question would be what is the best practice for passing some view model to a partial view while creating a request result at a response to submitting data to your server on http post.

Comment: I understand that I was not saying that a partial view is the same thing as a view model. I just wanted to know in the use case i described can i use a view model to accomplish this without using a partial view.